# Почему выводится 2 раза информация в запросе и при чем выводит не все элементы SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Здраствуйте! У меня 2 раза выводится та же самая информация в запросе. Я не понимаю что делаю не так, ибо код этого запроса верный, а на моем примере не получается. У меня база данных автосалона, где есть таблицы Машины, Работник, Покупатели, Работник_Инфо, и дополнительная таблица для создания связи многое к многому между таблицами Работник-Машины. Нужно сделать запрос, чтобы вывелась фамилия работника и все машины, которые он обслуживает. В таблице Employee_Cars я указала кто какую машину обслуживает, но оно почему-то не выводиться. Спасибо заранее!

Код программы:

```
USE Auto
GO

CREATE TABLE Customer
(Customer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 FirstName VARCHAR(20),
 LastName VARCHAR(20),
 NumberPhone VARCHAR(20) 
);
CREATE TABLE Cars
(Cars_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 Customer_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(Customer_ID), 
 Model VARCHAR(20),
 Year INTEGER
);
CREATE TABLE Employee
(Employee_ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 [Name] VARCHAR(20),
 Surname VARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee_Info
(Employee_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(Employee_ID),
 Sex VARCHAR(20),
 Age INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE Employee_Cars
(Employee_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employee(Employee_ID),
 Cars_ID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cars(Cars_ID), 
); 
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(1, 'Julia', 'Korobeiko', '+380993675603');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(2, 'Bohdan', 'Novak', '+380978114567');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(3, 'Denys', 'Korolchuk', '+380995479614');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(4, 'Ivan', 'Malesh', '+380660893012');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(5, 'Mykola', 'Malchevskiy', '+380994631290');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(6, 'Maria', 'Voitovych', '+380951175044');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(7, 'Sofiia', 'Obnyavka', '+380996415374');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(8, 'Oksana', 'Botsko', '+380997854521');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(9, 'Nataliya', 'Horobets', '+380505409687');
INSERT INTO Customer VALUES(10, 'Eduard', 'Domalchuk', '+380660893046');

INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(1, 1, 'Audi', 2021);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(2, 1, 'Mersedes', 2020);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(3, 3, 'Porshe', 2018);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(4, 4, 'BMW', 2020);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(5, 5, 'Wolksvagen', 2019);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(6, 6, 'Lexus', 2018);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(7, 7, 'Mazda', 2021);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(8, 8, 'Citroen' , 2018);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(9, 9, 'Renault', 2015);
INSERT INTO Cars VALUES(10, 10, 'Opel', 2021);

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(1, 'Valerii', 'Hlukhov');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(2, 'Anatoliy', 'Melnyk');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(3, 'Hennadii', 'Boiko');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(4, 'Roman', 'Popovych');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(5, 'Roman', 'Dunets');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(6, 'Olena', 'Horina');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(7, 'Roksolana', 'Oberyshyn');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(8, 'Lyubomyr', 'Tsygylyk');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(9, 'Ivan', 'Moroz');
INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(10, 'Maria', 'Nohal');

INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(1, 'Male', 55);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(2, 'Male', 65);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(3, 'Male', 66);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(4, 'Male', 64);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(5, 'Male', 67);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(6, 'Female', 50);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(7, 'Female', 30);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(8, 'Male', 31);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(9, 'Male', 50);
INSERT INTO Employee_Info VALUES(10, 'Female', 30);

INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(1, 10);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(1, 3);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(2, 2);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(3, 3);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(4, 4);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(5, 5);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(6, 6);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(7, 7);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(8, 8);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(9, 9);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(10, 10);
INSERT INTO Employee_Cars VALUES(10,2);
--Выводим Фамилию работника и машины которые он обслуживает
SELECT e.Surname, Cars.Cars_ID, Cars.Model
FROM Employee e
RIGHT JOIN Employee_Cars ec ON e.Employee_ID = ec.Employee_ID
RIGHT JOIN Cars ON ec.Cars_ID = Cars.Cars_ID
```

[image: результат]

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=541c647fea1de869927d9a8094adbeed не воспроизводится. зы: почему `right join` ? у вы, возможно, дважды в таблицу связи вставили строки?

Comment: здраствуйте, нет, я не вставляла, весь скрипт я сюда закинула

Comment: ну вот ссылка на фиддл приведена с вашим скриптом. все работает без повторов

Comment: Добрый день. У меня, вот, тоже не получилось проблему воспроизвести. проверьте, пожалста, нет ли дубликатов в Employee_Cars ?

Comment: здраствуйте, нет, проверяла, дубликатов нет. но когда я снова создаю базу даных, код воспроизводиться нормально. когда второй раз екзекючу запрос, появляються повторы

Answer (score 1):

Ответ в том, что надо использовать комманду `USE[ВАША_БАЗА_ДАННЫХ]`.

Я это не прописывала и мне все автоматически добавляло в системную базу данных master.